# Python Refreshing Pyplot Line from a Changing Length Array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, graph, line

I'm sure this has been asked, but I've had a very hard time finding a concise answer that works on searches. A few good answers seem to depend on calculating the final size of the array in advance. Seems like this should be very simple, and I'm a bit of a newbie so maybe I'm just searching the wrong terms ...

My Question is: 
**How do I get PyPlot to refresh the data of an existing line sourced from a numpy array of data, when the length of the array is unknown and changing over time?**

My current code is as follows

```
#Initial Setup    
changing_dataset = np.array(1) #initialize with a single blank y-value   
plt.close('all') #clear all the priors   
plt.ion()
f, axarr = plt.subplots(3,2) #setup a 3x2 plot ...only 1 shown below
axarr[0,0].set_title('My Plot')
line1, = axarr[0,0].plot(changing_dataset)
plt.show

... some code which appends new data to changing_dataset is omitted here...
```

then I simply want to do this:

```
line1.set_ydata(changing_dataset)
f.canvas.draw() 
f.canvas.flush_events()
plt.show()
```

In order to update the line in my initial plot, to now be based on the new, larger dataset contained in the array "changing_dataset".

But this generates an error like

*ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape*

How do I get around the requirement that seems to need the array to be of a static size? I would prefer to not need to re-title and build the plot from scratch - as the only thing that needs to change is the line (and possibly auto-rescaling the axes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A plot necessarily consists of x and y values. When setting `line1.set_ydata(new_y_data)` where `new_y_data` has a different length than the original y data, you break the correspondance of x and y values resulting in the shape mismatch error observed in the question.

If you want to change the number of y values in the plot, you need to change the number of x values as well.

Either use

```
line.set_xdata(new_x_values)
line.set_ydata(new_y_values)
```

or in one row

```
line.set_data(new_x_values, new_y_values)
```

In case you are plotting the y values against their index, the `new_x_values` would simply be the first n integers with n being the number of y values,

```
line.set_data(np.arange(len(new_y_values)), new_y_values)
```

Comment: That makes sense, and interestingly inputting the x values wasn't an original requirement, because as you suggest, I only intended to use the index for X. However, when I run the plot, while it no longer gives an error, it does not appear to refresh the chart as anticipated during my line.set_data() part of the loop ... it only generates the data if I go back to my original initializing statement of line1, = axarr[1,0].plot(np.arange(len(new_y_values)), new_y_values)

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. With the commands from the answer, the data of the line will be replaced by new values, such that the line chart is updated.

Comment: I think I figured it out - the missing piece is just my axes will need to be reset, as the initial values are basically nil, but as the dataset changes, we need to rescale with a loop that both relims and autoscales ...    `code`         axarr[a,b].relim()
axarr[a,b].autoscale_view() `code`